# Locally Euclidean spaces

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

**Problem**

> Prove that any nonempty open connected subset of a locally
> Euclidean space of dimension 1 can be made disconnected by
> removing two points.

**Definition of locally euclidean space**

> If Every point of $X$  has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or $H^{n}$ , the space is said to be locally euclidean space of dimension $n$.

**Question**

So from the definition it is clear that any open subset of locally euclidean space is again a locally euclidean space of same dimension. Therefore there exists open set in the open connected subset of a locally Euclidean space of dimension $1$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.Any two points removed from the set makes subset disconnected. Now how to show that open connected set becomes disconnected as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's true as stated. Let $X$ be the line with three origins. Take $U=X$ as your open set. Now remove two of the origins. What's left is the real line, which is connected. You can probably add a Hausdorff assumption to rectify things.

Comment: The question is about finding 2 points that makes  it disconnected. From your example, clearly any two points doesnot work.

Comment: But the line with three origins has no such two points, so is a valid counterexample.

Comment: I think removing any point other than 3 origins creates a disconnection